# Find the limiting distribution of $\frac{(2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta)}{\sqrt{n}X_{(n)}}$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, uniform-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, ... X_n \sim $ Unif$(0,\theta)$ and $X_{(n)} = \max X_i$

Find the limiting distribution of $\displaystyle \frac{(2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta)}{\sqrt{n}X_{(n)}}$

I know I should be using Slutskys because $X_{(n)} \to \theta$ in probability.

It seems that maybe I should re-write this as $\displaystyle \sqrt{n}\frac{(2 \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta)}{nX_{(n)}} = \sqrt{n}\frac{(2 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta/n)}{X_{(n)}}  $

Then we have that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to \mu = \frac{\theta}{2}$ by the Law of Large Numbers.

But then in the limit what we end up with is $\sqrt{n} \frac{(2 \frac{\theta}{2}-\theta)}{\theta} = 0$

So it seems I am doing this incorrectly.

EDIT: Using the comment below I can re-write as

$\sqrt{n}\frac{2 (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \theta/2n)}{X_{(n)}}$

Comment: I tried to figure it out, but couldn't. You might want to use the fact that $$\sqrt{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i - \dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) \overset{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \dfrac{\theta^2}{12} \right)\text{.}$$

Comment: @Clarinetist that is a good suggestion, I have edited it to include using that.

Comment: Your solution has an error. If you're going to multiply $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ by $1/n$, you must do the same to $\theta$. This is where I was stuck.

Comment: @Clarinetist yes you are correct

Comment: @Clarinetist I wonder if the question was meant to be $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(2X_i-\theta)}{\sqrt{n}X_{(n)}}$ because if so then there is no issue with a left over $n$.

Comment: I wonder the same.

Comment: Yes, the sum is exploding while the mean is converging to $\theta / 2$, should be a misplacement of the bracket